# Syntax error in sql SQL Status:42601

Tags: mysql

I want to list the id of the most common type of post history in 2013.

My code for just counting the numbers of how often each type comes up is correct:

```
SELECT  COUNT(id)  FROM post_history WHERE year = 2013 GROUP BY post_history_type_id ORDER BY COUNT(id)
```

Now I want to extract the maximum and just show the id of it. I tried it that way:

```
SELECT MAX(SELECT  COUNT(id)  FROM post_history WHERE year = 2013 GROUP BY post_history_type_id ORDER BY COUNT(id);) FROM post_history ;
```

But he says following error:

> FEHLER:  Syntaxerror at „SELECT“ LINE 7: SELECT MAX(SELECT  COUNT(id) 
>   FROM post_history WHERE year =...
>                      ^
>
> ********** Error**********
>
> ERROR: Syntaxerror at „SELECT“ SQL Status:42601 Zeichen:255

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: try removing semi colon(;) in query after "ORDER BY COUNT(id)"

Comment: instead of using MAX from sub query, you can just use LIMIT 1

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT post_history_type_id, COUNT(*)
FROM post_history
WHERE year = 2013
GROUP BY post_history_type_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: But I would like to use MAX(), is it not possible in my case?

Comment: @kellerprogger . . . If you use a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

try this query:

```
SELECT  MAX(number_count),post_history_type_id
FROM
(
        SELECT count(id) as number_count,post_history_type_id
        FROM    post_history 
        WHERE year = 2013
        GROUP BY post_history_type_id
)
```

Comment: okay  thanks, but in that case the post_history_type_id is stil missing in the output

Comment: I added a "as" at the end of the subquery and console says following: 
 ERROR: Column "xyz.post_history_type_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function